# Apache OSX 10.10 user permissions

Tags: macos, apache, sudo, osx-yosemite

I have noticed that on OSX Apache cannot be started unless it is sudoed.

Currently on my machine it is always started has root and I would like a specific user to have privileges to start it but do not know how to achieve that.

Can someone guide me through this please ?

Comment: This might be because port 80 (the default HTTP port) is in the "protected" < 1024 range; see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128134) on the UNIX Stack Exchange for more info on this topic. Try running it on another port, such as 8080 - if this solves your problem, then I'll remove this comment and post it as an answer instead so that it can be accepted.

Comment: I had tried that before but as the port 80 was required from another app it wasn't possible, but thanks anyway, this could work for anyone not requiring port 80 for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your web server is set up already, you're using `apachectl` from the command line and your user is called Peter, you can edit your sudoers file to allow Peter to run `apachectl` as root.

To do so, run `sudo visudo` and add this line to the file:

```
peter ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apachectl -k start
```

If Peter should be allowed to stop, restart and reload too:

```
peter ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apachectl -k start, /usr/bin/apachectl -k stop, /usr/bin/apachectl -k restart, /usr/bin/apachectl -k reload
```

Comment: That did it, thanks, that and closing Spotify which was using some of the dev ports for obscure reasons. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

From OSX 10.8 onward it seems more manual steps are required:
[Start Apache Web Server on MacOS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/)